# How can I check if eclipse is currently running?

Tags: c#, eclipse

I am trying to open eclipse from a C# application and would like to know if there is a way to know if Eclipse is currently running or not via C# code.

Comment: Did you try something post your code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get eclipse process with name

```
    var  process = Process.GetProcessesByName("eclipseProcessname");
```

and if `eclipseProcess` is null means eclipse is not running.

Comment: That doesn't exactly look like C#…

Comment: @Nuffin Why not?Process.GetProcessesByName("eclipseProcessname"); give a proccesses list

Comment: Do you know if I can get the location of the eclipse execution file from the process?